# Find standard deviation from text file with integers

Tags: arrays, double, text-files, bufferedreader, standard-deviation

I have a file containing a list of numbers that needs to be stored in an array. How can I compute the population standard deviation of the array? The Main class doesn't need to be altered.

**MAIN**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader; 

public class Main {
private static int NUMBERS=20;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] myNumbers =  new double[NUMBERS];
    Calculations calculations = new Calculations();
    try {
        calculations.readFile("numbers.txt", myNumbers);
        double stdDev = calculations.computeStandardDeviation(myNumbers);
        System.out.println("Population Std Dev = " + stdDev);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**CALCULATIONS**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Calculations {
// Read integers from text file, use myArray.length as the number to read 
// Read numbers as text and convert to doubles.
public void readFile(String fileName, double[] myArray) throws Exception {
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br;

}
public double computeStandardDeviation(double[] myArray) {
    double result = 0;

    return result;
}
}
```

**LIST**

9
2
5
4
12
7
8
11
9
3
7
4
12
5
4
10
9
6
9
4

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is "How to calculate the Standard Deviation of a population ?".

The calculation of the Standard Deviation (sd for short) is relatively simple.

To understand what sd means is beyond the scope of this answer so I'll go straight to the point. The sd is the "The squareroot of the average of the squared differences from the Mean".

Breaking down in steps (what programming is all about):

1st: Calculate the mean.

2nd: Now, for every value in the array, you need to calculate it's squared difference from the mean.

3rd: Add all the above values (call it s).

4th: Find the average squared difference (Variance) by diving s by the amount of numbers there are.

5th: Lastly, squareroot this last number you've got.

One example can be found [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html).

edit:

If you want a sample code for that, here it is (in Java):

```
public class Calculations {

public double computeMean( double[] array ){

    double sum = 0;

    for (double d : array){

        sum += d;
    }

    return sum / array.length;
}

public double computeStandardDeviation(double[] array) {

    double mean = computeMean(array);

    double sumOfSqDiff = 0;

    for (double d : array){

        sumOfSqDiff += Math.pow((d - mean), 2);
    }

    return Math.sqrt(sumOfSqDiff / array.length);
}
```